# How to update quantity of Cart when click + or - btn without refreshing page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Update quantity of shopping cart in session when click + or - button spinner and update without page reload.

I'm using html.BeginForm and it reloads the page every time I press the button

```
public ActionResult updateCart(FormCollection frc){
    string[] qty = frc.GetValues("qty");
    for (int i = 0; i < lsCart.Count; i++)
    {
        lsCart[i].p = Convert.ToInt32(qty[i]);
    }
    Session[strCart] = lsCart;
```

---

```
 <input type="text" name="qty" min="1" value="@cart.p"  />
 <button type="submit"></button>
 <button type="submit"></button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an AJAX call to accomplish that. Instead of html.BeginForm ajax.BeginForm is a possible solution. Have a look here: [Ajax.BeginForm](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/ajax-beginform-in-Asp-Net-mvc-5/)